Upvote comment is not working in the 'Late answers' review queue in Opera
I have came across an issue with Late answers review:
When I try to upvote an existing comment, instead of upvoting, it scrolls the website all the way up. If I open the page in a separate tab, upvote the comment and reload the review tab, it appears here and "other action" becomes active. This was experienced on Opera:
Opera One (version: 107.0.5045.36) 
System: Windows 11 64-bit 
Chromium version: 121.0.6167.186
This did not appear in other reviews, such as triage, first Q/A, and LQA. This problem has not appeared when I tried to conduct review on a different browser (I tried Microsoft Edge). Possibly it happens in multiple browsers, and I have run out of reviews today :)

Re "Late questions": By definition, questions can't be late (more or less). Do you mean "Late answers"? There is also "First questions".

@PeterMortensen yes just a mistake, title and tag says it all :) fixed though, it was already asked in a different thread anyways
